How much dried woodruff in vinegar?
Finding potted woodruff plants at the supermarket I took one, dried the sprigs for a few days, and put the leaves in vinegar to steep for 1-2 weeks in the fridge. The strained result would go over sweet salads or white fish.
But some time after plucking the dried leaves off with bare hands I had a slight funny feeling and bowel discomfort later in the evening. I infer that there's way too much woodruff in the jar for straight use, so I should top up the vinegar before final bottling.
There is now 1.1g dried woodruff leaves (a fluffy big handful) in 300ml vinegar 5%. How much should I dilute the infusion? Should I do it right now or can I let it steep out first?
Mods, please move to Medical.SE if you see fit.

I'm answering your post, because it contains an actual, answerable question. But please note that you seem to be a bit confused about some things. "I infer that there's way too much woodruff in the jar" - such inferences have a very low likelihood of being right, so they aren't part of how food safety works. The other are migration policies, if you're interested in those, there's a lot of explanation on Meta.SE.

There is no practically useful way of answering your question.
There is indeed a defined food safety limit for use of coumarin: 5 mg per kg food (source, in German). But since you just picked some wild woodruf, you can't measure its coumarin content, so there is no way to prove that you have stayed within the limit.
So, in the end, if you don't have access to a laboratory, you can't say anything about the safety of your woodruff-based food.

Ok. Actually it was a supermarket plant. But I guess another way of putting it is, how much dried woodruff for fresh - standard answer for generic herbs is 1:3 to 1:2. So according to most woodruff vinegar recipes I've got enough for 1.5L.

according to wikipedia "It has however not been found to be harmful to humans, even in large doses" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galium_odoratum#Uses_and_health_concern
